# Open PDF with headless browser Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, phantomjs

I have a pdf that is hosted on an s3 server, I would like to open the pdf and take screenshots within phantomjs. Everytime I get a status of fail. I looked around and cannot seem to find an easy solution

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var link = 'http://vfs.velma.com/Velma/testcard.pdf'; 
page.open(link, function(status) {
if (status!=='success') {
    console.log(status);
    phantom.exit();
} 
console.log(status);
phantom.exit();
});//ends page open()
```

I searched the docs but found nothing regarding opening a pdf. My ultimate goal is to screenshot the pdf and injecting an overlay image with jquery. Is this possible using only phantomjs and jquery?

Comment: The link gives error. Site is not reachable.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it as the pdf I am trying to link to is for work and is private. I tested it with several hosted pdfs. I will change the question to link to a reachable pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF file is not a webpage, so naturally PhantomJS will not render it. However there are projects and services that make possible rendering PDF in a browser, like Mozilla's [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) or Google's [online PDF viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ru/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html).

Since *those* produce valid HTML, you could work with them in PhantomJS.